# How to make pointcut that indicate child class's method call which didn't override parent's method?

Tags: spring-boot, junit5, spring-aop

There is one interface `Foo`, having two default methods `m1`, `m2`.

There are 3 classes `Foo1`, `Foo2`, `Foo3` implementing `Foo`. `Foo3` does not override method `m1`, but `Foo1`, `Foo2` do.

I want to create an aspect which targets `Foo3`'s `m1` method.

I tried `@Pointcut("bean(foo3) && execution(* *.m1(..))`, and it works properly while Spring Boot is running. But when I create a proxy object programmatically for unit testing, it does not work.

I know that `bean(foo3)` makes it work under Spring Boot, but I cannot find any alternative way to express the pointcut, which still works in the test. How can I make it work in this situation?

```java
public interface Foo {
    default Object m1() {
        // doSomething
        return Something;
    }

    default Object m2() {
        // doSomething
        return Something;
    }
}
```

```java
public class Foo3 implements Foo {
    // not overriding any method.
}
```

```java
@Component @Aspect
public class ExampleAspect {
    @Pointcut("bean(foo3) && execution(* *.m1(..))")
    public void exampleAspect() {}

    @Around("exampleAspect()")
    public Object proxyMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        // ...
        Object result = joinPoint.proceed();
        // ...
    }
}
```

```java
public Foo3Test {
    Foo instance = new Foo3();
    AspectJProxyFactory factory = new AspectJProxyFactory(instance);
    factory.addAspect(new ExampleAspect());
    Foo proxy = factory.getProxy();
    proxy.m1(); // it didn't use proxy. invoke real method.
}
```

I tried these pointcuts:

- `target(Foo3) && execution(* Foo.m1(..))` does not work even under Spring Boot
- `within(Foo3) && execution(* Foo.m1(..))` does not work even under Spring Boot
- `execution(Foo.m1(..))` works but all `m1` methods are proxied

Comment: Welcome to SO. Before looking into your problem, here are a few hints: It would be a good idea to learn a bit more about markdown formatting. You might want to check my edit and see what I have changed in your question. I little more care about orthography and punctuation might also be helpful to make the community here more inclined to read your question. Syntax highlighting, while not strictly necessary, certainly helps, too. Finally, a real [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of incomplete snippets with lots of "..." often also works wonders in getting helpful answers. 

Comment: @kriegaex First, thank you for correcting the question. I felt that previous answer was very poor and I need to study more about grammar, markdown.
I want to keep trying and become a developer who helps other like you.
Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not a Spring expert, but in order to make the special Spring AOP pointcut designator `bean` work, I guess you might need an application context in your test. Hoewever, I understand the need to create quickly running tests without all that ceremony. Fortunately, this is not difficult to achieve. Simply change your pointcut to:

```java
@Pointcut("target(Foo3) && execution(* m1(..))")
public void exampleAspect() {}
```

I tried, it works beautifully. Here is how I tested it:

```java
package de.scrum_master.spring.q76824399;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Aspect
public class ExampleAspect {
  @Pointcut("target(Foo3) && execution(* m1(..))")
  public void exampleAspect() {}

  @Around("exampleAspect()")
  public Object proxyMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println(joinPoint + " -> " + joinPoint.getTarget());
    return joinPoint.proceed();
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.spring.q76824399;

import org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AspectJProxyFactory;

public class Foo3Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExampleAspect aspect = new ExampleAspect();
    Foo[] instances = { new Foo1(), new Foo2(), new Foo3() };
    for (Foo instance : instances) {
      AspectJProxyFactory factory = new AspectJProxyFactory(instance);
      factory.addAspect(aspect);
      Foo proxy = factory.getProxy();
      proxy.m1();
    }
  }
}
```

And this is the console log:

```
10:45:11.823 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.ReflectiveAspectJAdvisorFactory - Found AspectJ method: public java.lang.Object de.scrum_master.spring.q76824399.ExampleAspect.proxyMethod(org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint) throws java.lang.Throwable
10:45:12.055 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.ReflectiveAspectJAdvisorFactory - Found AspectJ method: public java.lang.Object de.scrum_master.spring.q76824399.ExampleAspect.proxyMethod(org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint) throws java.lang.Throwable
10:45:12.071 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.ReflectiveAspectJAdvisorFactory - Found AspectJ method: public java.lang.Object de.scrum_master.spring.q76824399.ExampleAspect.proxyMethod(org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint) throws java.lang.Throwable
execution(Object de.scrum_master.spring.q76824399.Foo.m1()) -> de.scrum_master.spring.q76824399.Foo3@6eda5c9
```

Please note how the aspect finds all 3 instances of `Foo1`, `Foo2`, `Foo3`, but the advice is only triggered for the `Foo3` instance.

Comment: I tried, but it did not work.
And I found  that `@Pointcut("target(Foo3)")` did not work ether...
I think the sample code I wrote may not match the actual code.
Thank you for your asnwer

Comment: Then I recommend you to condense your project into the minimal, complete version still reproducing the problem, possibly anonymising class and package names. Then publish it on GitHub, and I can take another look.

Comment: Besides, if your test class is not in the exact same package as `Foo3`, you need to use a fully qualified class name `my.package.Foo3` in the pointcut.

Comment: While i making sample project that minimize information of origin project, I found the reason!

I omitted below 2 parts
1. There is other aspect which target `Foo.m1` `FooAspect` 
2. ExampleAspect has annotation `@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE` (import org.springframework.core.Ordered.
When I remove `@Order` annotation placed on ExampleAspect, It works properly on designator `target(Foo3)` what you said.
I found that if `@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE` annotated,
target(Foo3) did not work.
I'm sorry to i can't upload my code to github,. My company didn't allow it :(

Comment: Thanks for your help!! Now I'm going to check why the target doesn't work if there's `@Order` annotation

Comment: Read again! Nobody asked for your original code, I even explicitly talked about anonymising it. Therefore, "the company didn't allow it" is simply a lame excuse. Sorry to be so blunt, but I want to be very clear about this. I am so tired of the same excuse by lazy people here over and over again.

Comment: I'm sorry about that. I mean uploading code rejected by network level. I made sample code anonymising origin but refused to upload it.

Comment: There was also a way to upload anonymized code outside of company, but I'm sorry I didn't. I don't feel comfortable because I've disappointed someone who tried to help. I'm sorry about that.